# Type of the null value using F#

Tags: types, f#, null

Is there any way to get a type of the null value? This does not work:

```
let a: string = null
let typ = a.GetType()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let getStaticType<'T>(_x : 'T) = typeof<'T>
let a : string = null 
let b : int[] = null
let typ1 = getStaticType a
let typ2 = getStaticType b
printfn "%A %A" typ1 typ2
// System.String System.Int32[]
```

Comment: I don't know if that is valid F#, but it looks close enough to what I was expecting to see so +1 lol

Comment: Nice. You can also drop the input value instead of binding it to _x. `let getStaticType (_:'T) = typeof<'T>`.

Answer (score 5):

The solution by Brian probably does what you need, but you shouldn't need it in practice.

**Runtime type -** If you really need to detect the type of value at runtime (using `GetType`) then it is probably because the type may be more specific than what the static type suggests (i.e. it was de-serialized or created using Reflection and you got a value of type `obj` or some interface). In that case, you need to handle `null` explicitly, because `getStaticType` will always give you `obj`:

```
let handleAtRuntime (value:obj) =
  match value with 
  | null -> // handle null
  | _ -> let typ = value.GetType()
         // do something using runtime-type information
```

**Static type -** If you just need to know the `System.Type` of a statically-known type, then you should be able to write all you need using `typeof<_>`. This is useful when you have generic functions:

```
let handleStatically (value:'T) =
  let typ = typeof<'T>
  // do something with the type (value still may be null)
```

In your example, you don't really need any dynamic behavior, because you can be sure that the type of the value is `string`, so you can use Brian's solution, but using `typeof<string>` would be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is the best answer, but you can use Quotations to retrieve the type with.

For example:

```
let get_type x = <@ x @>.Type.FullName
```

And test:

```
let a : string = null
let a' = get_type a

val a : string = null
val a' : string = "System.String"

let a : int[] = null
let a' = get_type a

val a : int [] = null
val a' : string = "System.Int32[]"
```